# Understanding diff file

Tags: git, diff

I cannot understand what the diff file output means below. Can somebody explain what is going on, using some examples from the diff file excerpt, perhaps? Thanks.

```
4,8c4,8
< 12.0.90.53,91,2
< 12.1.241.148,207,2
< 12.1.96.104,375,4
< 12.1.96.104,4184,2
< 12.1.96.104,68397,2
---
> 12.0.90.53,92,4
> 12.1.241.148,207,4
> 12.1.96.104,379,7
> 12.1.96.104,4,2
> 12.1.96.104,9,2
10,29c10,23
< 12.10.160.114,61,2
< 12.10.216.130,106,6
< 12.10.216.130,1299114,1
< 12.10.219.26,85552,1
< 12.10.219.27,124,2
< 12.10.219.27,144417,3
< 12.10.219.27,171,2
< 12.10.219.27,218,1
< 12.10.219.27,233,3
< 12.10.219.27,246,3
< 12.10.219.27,439,1
< 12.10.219.27,806,1
< 12.10.219.28,13980,2
< 12.10.219.28,178675,5
< 12.10.219.28,435,1
< 12.10.219.29,236,1
< 12.10.219.30,1135645,1
< 12.10.219.30,175191,1
< 12.10.219.30,234,3
< 12.10.219.30,311,1
```

Comment: What exactly do you not understand? Be more specific. Besides, how are the `git` and `python` tags relevant, here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
diff file1 file2
```

'<' means - this line removed from file1 and '>' means this line added in file2